# Take substring out of string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a key string like

```
Empl:9998 Earn Code:7704 Seq:1
```

I need take the employee number 9998 out of the string.
The employee number will always start at position 6 and end before the second `E`.
I have been played around with all string function but no success. I use MS SQL.

Comment: All String functions? Even the [substring](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) one?

Comment: Should do little more digging before asking. I would say this question have been asked many times on StackOverflow itself.

Comment: Yes i do use substing but i could not get the length correct. and i should do more search. Sorry for that

Comment: Thanks, i accept Gordon Linoff's answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following statement will do this:

```
select substring(empno, 6,
                 charindex('E', empno, 6) - 6)
from (select 'Empl:9998 Earn Code:7704 Seq:1' as empno) t;
```

You might really want `-7` if you don't want the space in the "number".

Comment: Thanks i get result '9998 Earn'. but i really need is 9998. I may need more help with this

Comment: Thanks. I get it. I just a beginner and really precipitated your help. I guess i should do more research before i ask  question. Sorry for that. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

the [substring](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) function will get you started, but you'll also need [charindex](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx). (I recommend searching for the index of the space character)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT x = SUBSTRING('abcdef', 2, 3);

Here is the result set.    
x    
---- 
bcd
```

Answer (score 0):

this should always work

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"Empl:(\d+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
EmplyId = match.Groups[1].Value
```